# About my ISP give me a static IPV6 how can i use it and what it mean

Tags: networking, ipv6, ipv4, administrator

Hello guys I got a problem with IPV6 that my ISP give me. I don't really familiar with the IPV6 and this is the info that he gave me.

2001:0E68:5845:7500::/56
2001:0E68:5810:0B23::/64

what are those mean? can I use it to host a web server? can I use it on my DNS like Cloudflare?

/64 1 IPv6 subnet

what does that mean by 1 ipv6 subnet? what is the full address of that ipv6?

and this

/56 256 LAN segments

is it only used by LAN, not on WAN? what I mean is it's like we set up a webserver some IPV4 of our WAN will use at DNS for pointing that domain to ipv4. am so confusing right now please help me explain it to me.

Answer (score 0):

You will typically only use standard `/64` networks with IPv6, else you will break some IPv6 features (`/127` for point-to-point networks and `/128` for loopback addresses are the exceptions).

Your ISP is assigning the `/64` network as a transit network to reach your site. The `/56` prefix is a delegation, and your router should be able to automatically delegate `/64` networks for the individual networks in your site.

The `2001:0E68:5810:0B23::/64` is the full network address for the transit network between the ISP and your site, and you do not normally advertise or use this network in DNS.

The `2001:0E68:5845:7500::/56` is the delegated prefix from which your router can delegate individual standard `/64` networks for use within your site. You can use one of the `/64` networks to derive your `/127` point-to-point and `/128` router loopback addresses.

Search for IPv6 Prefix Delegation.

Because these are Global IPv6 addresses, you can assign them to DNS AAAA records. You need to make sure your ISP allows any services you want to provide (very likely with such an address allocation) and be sure to allow any public services (including requests) through your firewall.

Comment: What exactly is a "transit network"? Some kind of tunnel? How does this work?

Comment: No, not a tunnel. Routers route packets _between_ networks, so each router interface is in a different network. The transit network is the WAN link between the ISP equipment (PE) and your equipment (CE). It is a separate network from your LAN and the bulk of the ISP network. It exists with both IPv6 and IPv4, but because of the IPv4 NAT, you really do not need to think about it in the terms that a fully globally addressed LAN puts it in.